# Google Chrome Cache Purpose

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I have windows 7 and running a browser same to the google chrome (Slimjet) I have set it to cache Web Pages. and when i saw that folder every time it size gets bigger. I want to know what is the advantages of Cache in google chrome and its disadvantages.And what is stored in that  cache folder.

Comment: Did you try Googling it? Why did the found answers not suffice? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache

Answer (score 0):

The cache is an older method, dial-up for example, to speed up web pages. It stores the common content to your computer to use later.   On some current DSL and cable connections, this will speed up one's browsing experience!